# Handlebars Array Cycle

Tags: handlebars.js

I have this array:

```
{{#each weather.today }}
   <p class="VNAelement timeStamp">BlaBla</p>
   <p class="VNAelement">{{ rr }}mm</p>
{{/each}}
```

Now there will be three loops and on each loop the text `BlaBla` should be replaced. What is the best way to do this? The data comes from a json API but that string is set manuall.

Comment: Ideally, the Blabla should be a value from the `weather`, to loop it and display the different values

Comment: @GowthamShiva Unfortunately that is not the case :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to write a custom helper to check the array index during traversal.

But here, as you are sure of the number of loops (which is 3 array items), you can rely on the `@first` and `@last` data-variables.

```
{{#each weather.today}}
  <p class="VNAelement timeStamp">
    {{#if @first}}
      BlaBla-1 <!-- First item -->
    {{else}}
      {{#if @last}}
        BlaBla-3 <!-- Third item -->
      {{else}}
        BlaBla-2 <!-- Second item -->
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  </p>
  <p class="VNAelement">{{ rr }}mm</p>
{{/each}}
```